# How to redirect to controller action from phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I have one phtml.

In there i m check one variable if that variable is null than it should be redirect to Controller action

I m trying this code:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'marketplace/vendor/selectcategory');
```

but using this code if variable is not null than also redirect but i don't want this. I need to redirect when variable is null

Comment: how you are assigning value to variable & also how you are checking your variable for null value ? please add all the related code

Comment: I m getting int value using post method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this...

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'marketplace/vendor/selectcategory');

exit()
```

better way to use JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">location.href = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'marketplace/vendor/selectcategory';  ?>';</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not do redirects from the template files.
You should do it form the controller before calling `$this->renderLayout()`.
Do something like this in your controller:

```
if (your condition here) {
     $this->_redirect('marketplace/vendor/selectcategory');
     return;
}
```

Comment: it gives error like this ` a:5:{i:0;s:127:"Invalid method Example_Marketplace_Block_Vendoraddproducts::_redirect(Array
(
    [0] => marketplace/vendor/selectcategory
)`

Comment: _redirect is function of controller,is not function of block